# VBScript That Finds A Value on a Webpage and Returns a Message Prompt

Tags: vbscript, scripting, find

I am attempting to create a script that checks an internal website for available licenses and reports back a message prompt to the user if there is a license available or not. The website search works just fine, however, I cannot correctly format the second message prompt. 
If I send the command to search for "5 licenses used" I want a message prompting that there are no licenses available. And if that value does not match, that there are licenses available.

The entire script could be re-written if necessary. Doesn't need to be a loop. Just want this working function.

```
Do
    Find "5 Licenses used","websiteaddress.com"
    Pause("60")'waiting for 60 minutes and repeat the action
Loop

Function Find(StrString,URL)
    Title = "License Check"
    'URL = "Websiteaddress.com"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    ie.Navigate(URL) 
    ie.Visible = false 'run ie in the background
    Do While ie.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext 
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set objRegex = New RegExp
    objRegex.Pattern = StrString
    objRegex.Global = False
    objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)

    For Each Match in Matches 
        MsgBox "There Are Currently No Licenses Available "  & URL, 64, Title
    Next
    If
        'No Match in Matches 
        MsgBox "There Are Licenses Available " & URL, 64, Title
    End If
End Function

Function qq(strIn)
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function

Function Pause(NbMin)
    WScript.Sleep NbMin*1000*60
End Function
```

Comment: Can you use schedule tasks to run your script at regular intervals rather than running a script indefinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the matches.

```
If Matches.Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox "There Are Currently No Licenses Available "  & URL,64,Title
Else
    MsgBox "There Are Licenses Available " & URL, 64,Title
End If
```